# get list element to be inline with parent list when using custom list counters

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this html:

```
<ol>
  <li>
    <ol>
      <li>hello world</li>
      <li>hello world</li>
      <li>hello world</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

and this css:

```
ol {
    counter-increment: alpha-list !important;
}
li::before {
    content: "(" counter(alpha-list, lower-alpha) ") " !important;
}
li{
  list-style:none;
}
```

My issue is that the first `li` in the nested `ol` is not inline with the first `li` in the outer `ol`, but rather pushed down onto its own line. See https://jsfiddle.net/x2q5594y/3/.

Is there any JavaScript or CSS that can be used to put both `li` elements on the same line?

Comment: For the task described I would recommend using table, tr, td HTML elements instead of the list. Regards,

Comment: I don't see any `inline` styling anywhere in your css. Why would you expect it to be inline?

Comment: I expected it to be inline because that seems to be the default for nested lists if you are not using custom list counters. It turns out that I needed to add display:inline to the parent li element, the inner ol, and the first li in the inner ol to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fiddled your fiddle. Is this what you mean?

https://jsfiddle.net/x2q5594y/6/

I've added these lines:

```
ol li::before {
  float: left;
}

ol ol li::before {
  float: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the default style of `ol`

```
ol {
    padding : 0;
}
```

Updated fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/x2q5594y/4/

Comment: Thanks, but I want the first element of the nested li to be on the same horizontal line as the parent li, not just left-aligned.

Comment: @joshua - You can achieve it via adding hierarchical css, check - https://jsfiddle.net/x2q5594y/5/

Answer (score 0):

add padding:0 to ol.

```
ol {
    padding:0px;
    counter-increment: alpha-list !important;
}
```